# Cant get an attribute of an element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this html:

```
<img src="http://localhost:82/Clone//images/hosts/Kinx_9843a.jpg" data-name="/images/hosts/K_9843a.jpg" alt="">
```

I am trying to get this:

```
$('body').on('click','.hostPic',function(){ 
    console.log($(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

Whenever the picture is pressed, I want to gets its data-name attribute, but it doesnt work.. I get `undefined` reported when I try to retrieve the attribute. Any reason why?

Comment: you don't have the class .hostPic on the img?

Comment: jQuery has a handy method for getting `data-` attributes: `$(this).data('name')`

Comment: hmm..interesing..damn..i wrapped it in a span..thats why..wait i will try to change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `hostPic` class to that image.

Additionally, you can just use `.data('name')`, but it doesn't actually make a difference.  Older browser may have trouble with `.data`, but it's never been a problem for me.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference until you start using `.data()` or `.attr()` to **set** values, then it makes a world of difference; it's safer to *always* use `.data()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment , Anthony , I didnt now that

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.hostPic').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('name'));
}
```

Comment: the OP binds a delegated handler, this code does not. If the image is dynamically generated, this code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image has the class 'hostPic' and then do the following in your jQuery:-

```
$('.hostPic').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('name'));
}
```

Comment: hmm..interesting..i didnt know you could retrieve the thing with teh function data

Comment: the OP binds a delegated handler, this code does not. If the image is dynamically generated, this code will fail.

Comment: It's the easiest way to retrieve the data attribute. However, if the attribute gets changed in the jQuery it doesn't always work in which case you'd need to revert to using .attr('data-name').

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me, maybe you are attaching the events wrong object, you can understand that by debugging the `this` object instead of `data-name`.

And another thing is if you are going to use `.data` just for read string you should use `.attr` as the `.data` caches and tries to convert the value its appropriate type like `number` or `JSON` it is a heavier process than `.attr`.

```
<img src="http://localhost:82/Clone//images/hosts/Kinx_9843a.jpg" data-name="/images/hosts/K_9843a.jpg" alt="">​

​$("img")​.click(function () { alert($(this).attr("data-name")); });​
```